# Listing active PostgreSQL foreign data wrappers

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data

I have a few foreign data wrappers set up from my main PostgreSQL database to other databases.  Is there a table I can query to list all of the FDWs? Unfortunately `select * from information_schema.schemata` doesn't give any hints about which schemas are foreign and which are local.

Comment: There is no such thing as a foreign schema.  Only schemas which contain (at least one? 
 Exclusively?) foreign tables.  And how would you turn a "foreign" schema into an "active" fdw?

Comment: @jjanes "IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA my_schema FROM SERVER my_server INTO my_server_my_schema;"

I assumed that postgres was representing the entire schema as foreign somehow, but it seems like the "IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA" is just a shortcut to make multiple pg_foreign_table entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you're looking for is in various [pg_catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) tables. [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) is the main table that represents all relations, normal or foreign; you can limit it to foreign tables by including `WHERE relkind='f'`. Information on the foreign data wrappers themselves is in [`pg_foreign_data_wrappers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-foreign-data-wrapper.html), on servers in [`pg_foreign_servers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-foreign-server.html), and on foreign tables in [`pg_foreign_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-foreign-table.html).

Start with `select relname from pg_class where relkind='f'` to just get a list of table names, and from there you can use the pg_catalog docs to find whatever other pieces of information you need for what you're trying to do.